# Layout (CSS grid not 100% of the page) there is a small gap between the content grid and the footer

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

## issue in the layout

**I want the layout to be 100% of the page but apparently there is a small gap at the bottom**
is there a way to make the layout 100% of the page unless i enter a rich content in one of the child grids then a scrollbar should appear.

> there is a gap in the layout, even tho the parent grid is set to 100vh 100wh.

```css
*{

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
     width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4.5% 95.5%;
  grid-template-rows: 7% 89% 4%;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "sidebar header"
  "sidebar content"
  "footer footer";

}


.header{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
        
}
.sidebar{
     grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #EDEDED;

}
.content{
     grid-area: content;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  display: grid;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;

}
.footer{
 grid-area: footer;
 background-color: green;


}


.img-circle {
 width: 70%;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 15%;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: inherit;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(52,73,94,.44);
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


.sidebar{ 
padding-left: 0;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.maintenance{
display:grid;
grid-template-rows: 15% 85%;
grid-template-areas: 
"maintenance-nav"
"maintenance-info"
}

.maintenance-nav{
 grid-area: maintenance-nav;
 background-color: ##f7f7f7;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #25aaff;
}
.maintenance-info{
 grid-area: maintenance-info;
 background-color: blue;

}

.components{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
 grid-template-rows: 10% 90%;
 grid-template-areas: 
 "components-name components-nav"
 "components-name components-data";
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.components-name{
 grid-area:components-name;
 background-color: red;
}

.components-nav{
 grid-area: components-nav;
 background-color: blue;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.components-data{
 grid-area: components-data;
 background-color: yellow;
}

.maintenance-nav > div {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 30px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 13%;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Roboto,Arial,"Droid Sans",sans-serif;
}

.components-nav-links li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 20px;

}

.components-nav-links li a{
 
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


.components-nav-links li a:hover {

 color:#419C99;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/custom.css') }}">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Layout grid -->
  <div class="grid">
    <!--header grid-->
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <!--sidebar grid-->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!--sidebar logo-->
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/fleet.png') }}" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img"></div>
    <!--nav list-->
    <div>


    </div>
    <!--contenant grid-->
    <div class="content">

      <div class="maintenance">
        <div class="maintenance-nav">
          <div>Components</div>
          <div>Worklist</div>
          <div>Running Hours</div>
          <div>Jobs Report</div>
          <div>Cost Estimation</div>
          <div>Logs</div>
        </div>
        <div class="maintenance-info">
          <div class=components>
            <div class="components-name"></div>
            <div class="components-nav">
              <nav>
                <ul class="components-nav-links">
                  <li><a href="#">Component Data</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Logs</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="components-data">Components data</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>




  </div>
  <!--footer grid-->
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.footer` is outside the `.grid` element, because you have too many closing `</div>`'s.

Try this one:

```
<div class="grid">
    <!--header grid-->
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <!--sidebar grid-->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!--sidebar logo-->
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/fleet.png') }}" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img"></div>
    <!--nav list-->
    <div>


    </div>
    <!--contenant grid-->
    <div class="content">

      <div class="maintenance">
        <div class="maintenance-nav">
          <div>Components</div>
          <div>Worklist</div>
          <div>Running Hours</div>
          <div>Jobs Report</div>
          <div>Cost Estimation</div>
          <div>Logs</div>
        </div>
        <div class="maintenance-info">
          <div class=components>
            <div class="components-name"></div>
            <div class="components-nav">
              <nav>
                <ul class="components-nav-links">
                  <li><a href="#">Component Data</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Logs</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="components-data">Components data</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  <!--footer grid-->
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

With this tool you can verify if your html structure is OK:
https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the display of the container `.grid` as `grid` and also have defined `grid-template-areas` within the container `.grid`. But, while writing markups in HTML file, you have put your `.footer` container outside the `.grid` parent container.